# undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm a newbie in Rails and I have a problem with ORM relationships.

When i access /admin/health_concerns_lists

This shows up.

```
Showing /Users/sbpipb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-a2cd9604c2d9/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #2):
1

  insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
```

Here is my relationships.

```
class HealthProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    #table - health_profiles
    has_many :health_concerns, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :health_concerns_lists, :through => :health_concerns ,dependent: :destroy
end

class HealthConcern < ActiveRecord::Base
    #table - health_concerns
    belongs_to :health_profile
    belongs_to :health_concerns_list
end

class HealthConcernsList < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "health_concerns_list"
    has_many :health_concerns, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :health_profiles, :through => :health_concerns_lists, dependent: :destroy
end
```

## Schema

```
health_profile
id
name

health_concerns
id
health_profile_id
health_concerns_id

health_concerns_list
id
name
```

I know, my naming convention sounds wrong.

Comment: Why would you want to assign `self.table_name` a value?

Answer (score 3):

```
class HealthProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    #table - health_profiles
    has_many :health_concerns, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :health_concerns_lists, :through => :health_concerns ,dependent: :destroy
end
```

I guess you need to correct this part:

```
class HealthConcern < ActiveRecord::Base
    #table - health_concerns
    belongs_to :health_profile
    has_many :health_concerns_list
end

class HealthConcernsList < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :health_concerns, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :health_profiles, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
class HealthProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    # ...
    has_many :health_concerns_lists, :through => :health_concerns, dependent: :destroy
end
```

into:

```
class HealthProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    # ...
    has_many :health_concerns_lists, :through => :health_concerns, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :health_concerns
end
```

For every model with `has_many through: ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing:

```
self.table_name = "health_concerns_list"
```

By Rails conventions you do not need to specify a table name for the model.  Them model name (`HealthConcernsList`) will be `tableize`'d to `health_conerns_lists`.

If you must us a singular table_name, try:

```
class HealthConcernsList < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.pluralize_table_names = false
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html#active-record

Comment: because the table name is actually "health_concerns_list"

Comment: If you can, I would rename the table because you are really going against Rails conventions by using a singular table_name.

Comment: @olleh Are you using Rails 4? Or Rails 3? Consider my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. but this doesn't solve the problem.    I'm using Rails 4.